# Future get(), does it block calls if it's not finished?

Tags: java, jdbc, future

I have a function in the `DAO` class that run a stored function on the data base. I only want this operation to run again if the previous call to this operation is finished. So my function returns a `Future` object.

```
public Future<String> storedFunctionResultFuture()
{
   // calls the stored function
   return new AsyncResult<String>(result);
}
```

Now if I call `storedFunctionResultFuture().get()`, will the `get()` method block the call if the stored function is still in the process of running / not finished yet?

Comment: @SagarPudi What? Did you read the question? This is very clearly on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

So, short answer is - yes.

Comment: If you want to know if there is a result just call `isDone`, see the aforementioned doc.